After updating the Android studio on Mac, the ios language part of the New flutter project is not coming out at all
After updating the Android studio on Mac, the ios language part of the New flutter project is not coming out at all.
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11842104, built on May 15, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.5
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
Dart (233.15271)
io.flutter (80.0.1)
New Flutter Project Image
Even if I reinstall a Xcode, it remains the same.
Even if I reinstall various Android studio, it remains the same, too.
The ios environment seems to be operating normally in visual studio code.

It looks like they removed it on purpose. See
https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/7439
They don't want you to use Objective C anymore.

Not only object-c, but also no swift. There is no ios language part itself.

The option isn't there because it's always swift now
